# redirect the stdout of an third-party module to /dev/null

Tags: python

Suppose such a minor program to play sound

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

bell_sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/me/Music/audio/bell.wav")
play(bell_sound)
```

Upon running it, the terminal got multiple lines of propts

```
In [8]: run report_time_example.py  
Input #0, wav, from '/tmp/tmpsc7u87_e.wav':   0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
  Duration: 00:00:01.62, bitrate: 176 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 176 kb/s
   1.43 M-A:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Manually redirect the output to /dev/null

```
   !python report_time_example.py  &> /dev/null
```

How could get the job done inside the python code body.

Comment: you could check in source code if it is even possible. Maybe functions in this module have some option for this. Or maybe you will have to modify source code.\

Comment: you may try to assign own function/class to `sys.stderr` but it can blocks all error messages.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate of that.

Comment: @AdamSmith, and why do you say that?

Comment: The practical example is good, but a [mcve] would be better

Answer (score 3):

[The `contextlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) offers [context managers to redirect `stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) and [`stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr) for precisely this purpose:

```
import contextlib
import os

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as null, \
     contextlib.redirect_stdout(null), contextlib.redirect_stderr(null):
    bell_sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/me/Music/audio/bell.wav")
    play(bell_sound)
```

While in the `with` block, `stdout` and `stderr` are redirected; when the block is exited, the original handles are restored.

Note: `redirect_stdout` was introduced in 3.4, and `redirect_stderr` in 3.5; if you're still on 2.7 or the like, your only option is reassigning `sys.stdout`/`sys.stderr` manually, or using `os.dup2` to replace the underlying file descriptors, but I'd recommend using modern Python first.